# Is it possible to change gps-camera properties in AR.js?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

Hey I have set up a Scene, where I use the simulate Coordinates property of the gps-camera. Like this:

```
<a-scene embedded arjs renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" gesture-detector
    id="scene">
    <a-marker type="pattern" preset="custom" url="pattern/ifgi-pattern.patt" id="ifgi-marker">
    </a-marker>
    <a-entity position="0 0 0" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5" gps-entity-place="latitude: <lat>; longitude: <lon>;"
      gltf-model="/gltf/truck_model/scene.gltf">
    </a-entity>
    <a-camera gps-camera="simulateLatitude: <lat>; simulateLongitude: <lon>;" rotation-reader id="camera">
  </a-scene>
```

Is it possible to change the `simulateLatitude`and `simulateLongitude`property?
Thanks for your help!